# Is this dish (or vessel) called "casserole"?

Tags: synonyms, image-identification

A Ukrainian book says that what I know as **cooking pot** is **casserole**. Now I checked Cambridge and Oxford dictionaries and there's not such definition for casserole. So before I'm going to tell my friend that it is a mistake I just want to be sure about that.

The only definition in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/casserole) for casserole:

> a dish made by cooking meat, vegetables, or other foods in liquid
>   inside a heavy container at low heat, or the heavy, deep container
>   with a lid used in cooking such dishes:

The definitions of [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/casserole) for casserole:

> 1. A kind of stew that is cooked slowly in an oven.
>
> 1.1 A large covered dish used for cooking casseroles.

How do these definitions have to do something with the **cooking pot** that we see in the picture as **casserole**?

[image]

Comment: Is the translation correct? This looks more like a [*stew pot*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stewpot&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images) to me. In the US anyway, casserole dishes are usually made of Pyrex, CorningWare or similar glass materials, not metal. But I imagine what constitutes a "casserole dish" (food-wise) varies from place to place.

Comment: Also see [*casserole dish*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=casserole+dish&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images).

Comment: It seems that it is more acceptable in the UK than other countries. I found one example from the UK. https://www.towerhousewares.co.uk/cookware-ovenware-c87/sauce-pans-c90/ceramic-finish-c91/tower-24cm-casserole-graphite-p94 But this is what I got when I googled **casserole** before: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=casserole&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCrcHRnLLbAhXE0aYKHdhYBFYQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662#imgdii=4ptaX91H9--TbM:&imgrc=HW2Kr9uw8ze-RM:

Comment: @Intrigued_by_proliferation It seems that your search shows casseroles (food). Have you tried searching "casserole pot" (cookware)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your book is right and that point is reflected in the meaning that you have already found in Oxford Dictionary

> 1.1 A large covered dish used for cooking casseroles.

The cookware used for making casseroles is also known as casserole, casserole pot or casserole dish. This last one seems to be used to name the object used to serve the casserole instead of the object used to cook it.

Maybe the image that appears in your book is not exactly how modern casseroles (pot) look like but the cooking pot used for making casseroles is the casserole.